# Jquery Scrolling Smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code which works but the scrolling is too abrupt and fast. I would like to make it much smoother and slower.

```
 document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This will be tricky to answer unless you provide a working demo of your issue.

Comment: Actually it works as intended in Chrome but not in Safari and Firefox...

Comment: Then don't use `scrollIntoView` - use `animate` or similar.